# How to explicit execute begin (commit, rollback) transaction with PlatformTransactionManager?

Tags: spring, spring-data, sap-ase

I'm using Spring `PlatformTransactionManager` with jTds and Sybase ASE 16.

I cannot use AutoCommit because it will `SET CHAINED ON` and the database I'm working has triggers with unchained procedures.

So my connection has `SET CHAINED OFF` (AutoCommit=false).

In this scenario, SYBASE ASE **requires** explicit `begin transaction`, `commit transaction` or `rollback transaction`. If not, it will completely ignore any transaction.

I'm looking for a way to tell the `PlatformTransactionManager` to execute `begin transaction`, `commit transaction` or `rollback transation`. Is it possible?

Update -> My configuration:

```
spring.sybase.url=jdbc:jtds:sybase://hostname:6000/db;autoCommit=false;appName=integration
spring.sybase.username=myuser
spring.sybase.password=mypass
spring.sybase.driver-class-name=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
spring.sybase.hikari.pool-name=datasource-pool
spring.sybase.hikari.connection-timeout=3000
spring.sybase.hikari.maximum-pool-size=5
spring.sybase.hikari.minimum-idle=0
spring.sybase.hikari.transaction-isolation=TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
spring.sybase.hikari.auto-commit=false
spring.sybase.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
```

Bean Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SybaseDataSourceConfig {
    public static final String SYBASE_JDBC_TEMPL = "sybaseJdbcTempl";
    public static final String SYBASE_DS = "sybaseDs";
    public static final String SYBASE_DS_PROPERTIES = "sybaseDsProp";
    public static final String SYBASE_TRAN_MANAGER = "sybaseTM";


    @Bean(name = SYBASE_DS_PROPERTIES)
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.sybase")
    public DataSourceProperties sybaseDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = SYBASE_DS)
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.sybase.hikari")
    public HikariDataSource sybaseDataSource(@Qualifier(SYBASE_DS_PROPERTIES) final DataSourceProperties sybaseDataSourceProperties) {
        return sybaseDataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = SYBASE_JDBC_TEMPL)
    public JdbcTemplate sybaseJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier(SYBASE_DS) final HikariDataSource sybaseDataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(sybaseDataSource);
    }

    @Bean(name = SYBASE_TRAN_MANAGER)
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier(SYBASE_DS) final DataSource sybaseDataSource) {
        DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
        dataSourceTransactionManager.setDataSource(sybaseDataSource);
        return dataSourceTransactionManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to use auto-commit? You don't need to manuall start/stop transactions, just use `@Transactional` to mark the transactional unit.

Comment: Yes, but it's a Sybase thing, @Transactional is working, I can see the logs, but sybase won't do the effective transaction If I don't explicitly call "begin transaction".

Comment: Which would be strange as that is the whole poit of `@Transactional` and is probably a wrong configuration of your jdbc driver. Manually calling start/commit/rollback on the transaction manager won't help.

Comment: Yes, I agree it's weird, but that's how Sybase ASE works. Using pure jdbc with the `begin transation` the query block works, with `@Transactional` it does not (I checked with enabling the logs, it's all ok with it, execpt Sybase won't obey).

Comment: I still believe it is a configuration thing on your side (as the jdbc driver should automatically write those statements when `begin` is called on the connection). so please provide your configuration.

Comment: Do you have multiple datasources and transaction managers, as it appears you are using Spring Boot. If you are using `@Transactional` without defining explicitly which one to use, it will use the default which might be the one that isn't bound to sybase. If you aren't using multiple and are using Spring Boot your configuration can be deleted (and rename some of the properties).

Comment: I have two datasouces and I'm specifying which TransactionManager to use: `SYBASE_TRAN_MANAGER`

Comment: Specify it where? In the `@Transactional`? Are you using plain JDBC or do you use JPA? In the latter case you are using the wrong tx manager.

Comment: I'm using Springs `JdbcTemplate`, not JPA.

Comment: Can you add some code where transactions are started/used. Because when opening the transaction the driver should submit those statements. If that isn't happening there must be something wrong.

Comment: I solved it by using jConn4 instead of jTDS (which isn't updated since 2013).